# disable mousedown bind event on scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery

on the http://www.associationtsunami.org/ site if i make a mousedown on the document the cube rotates depending on the direction the user moves the mouse.

the code is:

```
key code ...
).bind('mousedown touchstart', function (evt) {
        delete mouse.last;
        if ($(evt.target).is('a, iframe')) {
          return true;
        }
        evt.originalEvent.touches ? evt = evt.originalEvent.touches[0] : null;
        mouse.start.x = evt.pageX;
        mouse.start.y = evt.pageY;
        $(document).bind('mousemove touchmove', function (event) {
          dragging = 1;
          // Only perform rotation if one touch or mouse (e.g. still scale with pinch and zoom)
          if (!touch || !(event.originalEvent && event.originalEvent.touches.length > 1)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            // Get touch co-ords
            event.originalEvent.touches ? event = event.originalEvent.touches[0] : null;
            $('.viewport').trigger('move-viewport', { x: event.pageX, y: event.pageY });
          }
        });
        $(document).bind('mouseup touchend', function () {
          dragging = 0;
          $(document).unbind('mousemove touchmove');
        });
      });
```

full code https://github.com/AssociationTsunami/tsunami/blob/gh-pages/js/cube.js#L72

i would like to disable this event if a user makes the mousedown on a scrollbar - for example on the 'ONSONPARLA' page there is a TAB with ACCORDIONS, if you open any of the accordion content you get a scrollbar on the edge or within the accordion and if you try to move the scrollbar, this also moves the cube.

what is the correct way to overwrite this in the cube.js so that the cube does not turn if the event is on a scrollbar element?

Comment: This is completely unrelated to your question, but just a friendly tip: don't use gimmicky things like spinning cubes in your interface. A low key interface with nice typography and a good color scheme is WAAAYY more important than 3D spinningness. `</unrelatedrant>`

Comment: This page hurts my feelings :)

Comment: you really don't learn much if you just keep to the same old low key interface!

Comment: you're visitors don't learn anything when the website it as unusable as that example is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done in such manner.

But there is an alternative solution. Use some custom scroll bar plugin to replace classic scroll bar. You will be able to prevent events on him. I understand this is not an excellent solution, but according to you web page you like to take a chance. :)

[Here](http://www.codeinsects.com/7-beautiful-custom-scrollbar-jquery-plugins.html) you can find few good plugins.

Good plugin example is [here](http://www.minimal.com.hr/#/resume).